# overloaded new operator returning NULL memory for new object everytime

Tags: c++, new-operator, c++98

I am trying to return NULL from an overloaded new operator function every time. Here is my program

```
class xxx{
      int n;
      public:
             void* operator new(size_t){
                   cout<<"in operator new"<<endl;
                   throw std::bad_alloc();
                   //return (void *)NULL;         //LINE COMMENTED
                   }
};
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
   xxx *x1=new xxx;
   if(x1)
      cout<<sizeof(x1);
   else
      cout<<"Unable to allocate memory"<<endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Here if I use the line `return (void *)NULL;` then pointer x1 gets created which is not intended for this program.

And if I use the line `throw std::bad_alloc();`, then program gets terminated/crashed instantly.

Now I want to know if there is any way if we can bypass "new operator" not to allocate memory for an object.

Comment: I think there is some confusion as to what you are trying to do. When you say "pointer x1 gets created", then that means, if taken literally, that there is a pointer variable x1 (which occupies the storage necessary to hold an address, on PCs often 4 bytes). That in itself is no surprise because you declared and defined that variable. But what's interesting is what it _points_ to. If `new` returns the null pointer, the variable will contain an address which  is invalid on all platforms. So while the _pointer_ surely is created, no _memory_ is allocated. Does that help?

Answer (score 2):

This code works fine (tested with MSVC from VS2010) and always returns `nullptr` for `X` allocation, as requested in your question:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class X {
public:
    X() { cout << "X::X()" << endl; }

    static void* operator new(size_t size) {
        return nullptr;
    }
};

int main() {
    X* px = new X();
    if (!px) {
        cout << "Allocation returned nullptr." << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "Allocation succeeded." << endl;
        delete px;
        px = nullptr;
    }
}
```

Note that in modern C++11, you may want to use `nullptr` instead of C++98/03 `NULL`.

Note also that the `(void*)` cast you used in your code is useless.

Moreover, if you use `throw std:bad_alloc();` inside your custom implementation of `new`, the program "crashes" beacuse you throw an exception that is never caught.
If you insert a `try...catch(const std::exception&)` block in your `main()`, you can make your program exit in a more "controlled" way (including printing some error message).

Comment: Is there any means to solve in C++98. Since I have not migrated to c++11.

Comment: You may want to use `NULL` (C++98) instead of `nullptr` (C++11).

Comment: @Santosh i believe returning NULL as @Mr.C64 suggested is the proper solution in this case. Oddly enough, that's what you were doing but commented out the line. Also, I took freedom to tag your question with C++98 to be strict about that. C++11 changes a lot of things because it allows you to explicit `delete` the operators, thus disallowing the creation of the object that way.